# How can I extend the partition of Ubuntu when it's installed on the last partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

As can be seen in the picture

[image: partitions on my disk]

My Ubuntu is installed on `/dev/sda4`, which is located after the unallocated space. I neither can resize `/dev/sda4`, `/dev/sda5` nor `/dev/sda6`.

Is there any way to extend my Ubuntu?

Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu on a previous partition such as `/dev/sda2`?

Comment: How much space do you need?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the unallocated space could be made into another partition and called sda3. If you installed ubuntu in that space it would be bigger than what you have now. You can also resize the extended partition (sda4); see [How to Expand , Resize "extended partition"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591213/how-to-expand-resize-extended-partition) . You will need to boot into a live distribution to make these changes since they affect your root partition.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to resize the extended partition (`aka /dev/sda4`) to make some room
   [image: resize extended partition]
2. to move the start of `/dev/sda5`
   [image: move sda5]
3. and then later grow/resize `/dev/sda5`.
   [image: grow sda5]

Comment: How can "to make some room" be a list item there?